# Why are constructible numbers strict proper subsets of computable numbers?

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-geometry, computer-science, computability

Well, obviously $\pi$ is transcendental, therefore not in the algebraics.  Constructibles are clearly a subset of the algebraics so $\pi$ is not constructible. Yet $\pi$ is computable. Thats a perfect counter example as to why the constructibles are a proper subset of the computables.

But Im having a hangup nonetheless.  My comprehension of what makes a number computable is, in essence, what is conjured in my imagination by the colloquial term "computer". Maybe thats where my hangup is. Every definition I read, and I admit Im no expert, seems to imply the standard notion of computation, i.e. what computers do. Some definitions explicitly reference computers, algorithms, programs, or Turing machines; others are a bit more vague notions of logical languages.  Algorithms and functions arent defined in context, but I suppose they mean a sequence of defined mathematical functions and operations, allowing for reiteration and conditional branching, and terminating in a finite quantity of said operations.  Ultimately though, converging with arbitrary precision to the target "computed number" within the reals.

Okay, fine. But how is that different than what is constructible?  Euclidean geometery allows me to add, subtract, multiply, divide and take square roots with infinite precision (ideally, of course). But there are more operations here than what a computer can do!

Sure, you can program a computer to implement transcendental functions (but even they are just approximations with arbitrary precision, typically implemented with Taylor series).  At the heart of a computer, all you have is addition, implemented in bit logic at an electronic level. But thats literally it!  A computer isnt capable of more; everything else is just a cosmetic interpretation of those 1's and 0's stored in memory. All operations - ALL of them - are ultimately implemented using addition (okay, you have bit shifting too but that is essentially just doubling, i.e. adding to itself).

And addition is one of the five basic operations in Euclidean geometry. So how is it then that a computer can resolve more numbers than what is constructible? It seems to me that I should be able to evaluate even more numbers and with better precision than what any real computer can ever do, simply by implementing the same operations one would carry out in a computer but in a Euclidean construction instead, making deliberate choices.

Where is my failure?

Comment: Could you precisely state the definitions you use for “constructible” and “computable”? One thing to keep in mind is that every constructible number is completely specified by finitely many operations but a computable number need not be.

Comment: ps even among the algebraic numbers the constructibles are quite special, always having degree a power of 2 over Q

Comment: @TokenToucan Every definition of computable Ive seen does require (or implies) a finite number of operations. Am I wrong?  References to algorithms or turing machines or to prescribed tolerances in precision implies, to me, a point of termination.  A program that doesnt terminate doesnt produce a value answer. Im un-inclined to think your point holds merit; please do prove it.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: A computable real cannot in general be specified by a finite sequence of operations. Rather, given a specified degree of precision, it can be specified **to that degree of precision** by a finite sequence of operations.

Comment: It is not a test... there are different definitions so to answer you most effectively one would need to know the ones you use... Based on your response you are certainly misunderstanding some definition of computable but if you don’t articulate that definition then it’s not very easy to explain the definition more clearly.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum "Every definition of computable Ive seen does require (or implies) a finite number of operations. Am I wrong?" You're mistaking the *program* for *what it does*. The program computing a real number is indeed a finite object, but the computation itself isn't: to compute the real to more and more precision requires more and more steps. TokenToucan is exactly right.

Comment: Thanks be to @BrianM.Scott for a competent and quick response that does indeed shed light on my mistake. Thanks for not dragging it out and making it an issue and just getting to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Briefly, a real number $r$ is constructible if it can be expressed **exactly** as a combination of some "basic functions" applied to some "basic starting numbers." That "exactly" is crucial here: a process by which we produce constructible numbers closer and closer to $r$ without every reaching $r$ itself is **irrelevant** to the constructibility of $r$ itself.

By contrast, those limiting processes are exactly what **computability** is about: $r$ is computable if we can computably find a sequence of rationals which converge to it quickly (usually we require specifically that the distance between the $e$th and $(e+1$)th rational is $<2^{-e}$).

So there's just a fundamental type difference here. It will help to consider a concrete example of a problem which is "geometrically unsolvable but computationally solvable" - for example, trisecting an arbitrary angle. There is no finite sequence of "basic geometric operations" which will produce the desired result exactly, but it is nonetheless computable in the appropriate sense.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum If you want to talk about terminating at a finite step, the specific choice of model of computation becomes important. For example, in the definition I gave above, terminating at a finite stage means that you're *rational*! While the overall notion of "computable number" is model-invariant, variations like "finite-time computable" are not. You can indeed whip up a "geometry machine" whose "finite-time computable" numbers are exactly the constructible numbers.

Comment: And then there are models where it simply doesn't make sense to talk about "early-terminating computations." For example, the **Dedekind-cut** definition of "computable real number" is: $r$ is computable if there is an algorithm $\alpha$ such that for each rational number $p$, $\alpha$ tells us whether $p<r$ or $p\ge r$. Note that it's never the case that finitely many runs of $\alpha$ pin down $r$ exactly.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum OK, it was just an example intended to build intuition. I could have used anything else similar, the point was to just look at a familiar situation where there's a geometrically impossible problem which is trivially computationally possible in the relevant sense.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum "I feel as though your definition of computable in terms of rationals is far too similar to the dedikind cut definition of the reals themselves." Um, OK ... too bad, it's one of the valid definitions. (There is another definition of computable number in terms of computable Dedekind cuts, FYI - see a couple comments above.) I'm not sure what you're getting at here.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I didn't say I was done with this conversation, I said I don't know what you're getting at here. And I don't. I haven't been "snarky" here once. You seem extremely quick to leap to negative interpretations of other people's comments (here and above).

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum "A dedekind cut is basically how you defined the the computables, without actually using the term." Not sure what you mean - it's **one of** the ways to define them, but there are lots of equivalent definitions (and I've given two, one in terms of Cauchy sequences and one in terms of Dedekind cuts). "A sequence (or set, for all the diffrence it makes)" Actually, it's quite an important difference once one gets past the basic definitions; it's not at all a silly thing to point out.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I don't think this comment thread is a good place to hash out issues of ettiquette. "I guess this bit is just a little over my head for the time being. Or else I need a little more one-on-one direction." Definitely let me know any specific questions you have and I'll see if I can help. (FYI if you comment with a question I'll probably edit the answer to address it rather than respond with another comment - in order to keep the comment thread length down. You'll still get a ping notification though.)